# Unlock app for removing ads

Tags: android

I have  a free app with ads and created now a "unlocker"-app to remove them.
The unlocker app is starting the main app, and the main app is checking if the unlocker app is installed and write it in the preferences.

Is this the right way for a unlocker app?

Its working but I dont know if this is the correct way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In most of the times if it's working then it's the way to do it! In your case you should tell us what is your goals, and we will tell you if your solution feet them all. For example if your goal is security so this is a bad solution as I can hack in your preferences by many ways. If your goal is average user experience, then it sounds as a good solution.

Comment: Thank you! Yes modify sharedpref is very easy with a rootet phone. The goal is only to remove ads. It would be great to do sth. like a signature check for my unlocking app